# Spectrum of the ring $k[T]/(T^2)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-verification

Consider the the ring $B = k[T]/(T^2)$ where $k$ is a field.

If $I$ is a prime ideal in $B$ then $I = (a + bT)$ for some $a,b \in
k$ (with $b \ne 0$). Then $T = a^{-1}T \cdot (a + bT) \in I$. Hence $(T) \subset I$ and
$(T^2) \subset (T) \subset I$. Since $b$ is invertible we can write
$$I = \left( b^{-1}(a+bT) \right) = \left( b^{-1}a + bb^{-1}T \right) = \left( c + T \right) \ . $$
Since $(T) \subset I$ we have that $(c + T , T) = I$ but that implies that $1 \in I$:
$$ I \ni c^{-1} (c + T) - c^{-1}T = 1 + c^{-1}T -c^{-1}T = 1 $$
if $c \ne 0$ and clearly $I = (T)$ also if $c = 0$.
Hence, $k[T]/(T^2)$ is a local ring with single prime and maximal ideal $I = (T)$. Note that $(0)$ is not a prime ideal as $T^2 = 0$ and $T \notin (0)$. Thus,
$$ \operatorname{Spec} k[T]/(T^2) = \{ (T) \}  $$
is a single point (as a set).

Is my analysis correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not making your life easier? There is no need to calculate with polynomials.

We have homeomorphisms

$\mathrm{Spec}(k[T]/(T^2)) \cong V(T^2) = V(T) \cong \mathrm{Spec}(k[T]/(T)) \cong \mathrm{Spec}(k) = \{\eta\}$

It maps $\eta$ to the kernel of $k[T]/(T^2) \to k[T]/(T) \cong k$, which is $(T)$.

In general, if $A$ is a commutative ring with a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and $n \geq 1$, then $A/\mathfrak{m}^n$ has a single prime ideal, namely $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^n$. Direct proof: The prime ideals of $A/\mathfrak{m}^n$ correspond to the prime ideals of $A$ containing $\mathfrak{m}^n$. But these have to contain $\mathfrak{m}$, i.e. have to be $=\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Thank you. But it useful also to do it hands and understand the prime spectrum of that ring.